# ListView has been removed from react native

Tags: android, react-native, listview, metro-bundler

I am facing the error:

```
ListView has been removed from react native
```

The error says that one of the modules that uses `Listview` is `react-native-photo-browser`. 
I am reinstalling the package but it still contains `ListView`.

More over, it is happening in `node_modules/metro`. How can I upgrade it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That `react-native-photo-browser` project has not been published to `npm` since removing `ListView` from its source. You can install the latest directly from github using:

`npm install github:halilb/react-native-photo-browser`

or

`yarn add https://github.com/halilb/react-native-photo-browser`

depending on your package manager.